# Batch if statements don't seem to work

Tags: batch-file

I am so confused and all help is appreciated...
so I'm making a little game and this is the code:

```
@echo off

:menu
echo Welcome To My Game!!!
echo Play & echo.Exit 
:: add more menu items above

set /p menInp= 

if /i %menInp%==play goto initFile
if /i %menInp$==exit EXIT

:initFile
cls
if NOT exist \MyAdventureGame\AdventureGameSave.txt\ GOTO newGame
if exist \MyAdventureGame\AdventureGameSave.txt\ GOTO Load

:newGame
echo. 2>AdventureGameSave.txt
set Gold = 50
set Xp = 0
set Level = 1
GOTO Save

:Save
echo %Gold% >>AdventureGameSave.txt
echo %Xp% >>AdventureGameSave.txt
echo %Level% >>AdventureGameSave.txt
GOTO Town

:Load
:: add Load functionallity here
GOTO Town

:Town
echo Welcome to town!!!
PAUSE
```

Now for my question...
when i run it, no matter what I type for my menInp, my program goes to the next line, :initFile, and its almost like my if statements

```
(if /i %menInp%==play goto initFile
if /i %menInp$==exit EXIT)
```

are being ignored.

Comment: Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Answer (score 0):

```
if /i %menInp$==exit EXIT
```

should be

if /i %menInp%==exit EXIT

or preferably

if /i "%menInp%"=="exit" EXIT

since you are unable to predict the user's input and it may contains spaces. The `"`s make the string a single token.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a comment, but may forestall further problems.

Tip for game-generation:

If you reserve a character as a prefix for variables-you-want-to-save (eg all variables I want to save/reload start with `#`) then all you need to *save* a game is

```
set #>"mygamefile.txt"
```

and all you need to *reload* a game is

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("mygamefile.txt") do set "%%a"
```

To zap all `#` variables (useful before reloading a game) use

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%a="
```

Oh  and you may consider removing the terminal `\` from the filename in the `if exist` statements (also enclose the entire filename in quotes to allow the name to contain spaces (and follow good practice regardless of whether you actually *need* to cater for spaces in filenames))